# How to use group by and select distinct

Tags: sql, firebird

I am using a Firebird database, but answers using SQL syntax of most other database engines are also acceptable.

I have two tables:

```
WORKER
workerid: integer
worker names and so ot.

LOGEVENT
logeventid: integer
logday: integer
workerid: integer
```

Thus LOGEVENT table is used to track worker logins. 
And for simplicity here I use logday as integer which is represent login day. For example, it could be a day of year from 1 to 365.

Therefore the typical log table may look like that:

```
logeventid   logday     workerid
1            5          3
2            5          4
3            5          3
4            5          7
5            6          4
6            6          3
7            6          4
```

As seen the worker with id = 3 did two logins on 5th day.

Now I need to create a SQL query producing total number of "unique" logins per day (several logins by the same worker during the same day should be counted as one event).

The following query:

```
select  count(logeventid) as logincount, logday from logevent
group by logday
order by logday
```

Will show logincount = 4 for 5th day. Because it counted worker with id = 3 twice. While I must have to count only distinct workers logins. So, I need a query producing only 3 logins for the 5th day.

Comment: Guess u should reformulate the question. "unique login event" is exactly what "A. van Esveld" told you - how many time any person, same or another, passed through the door. Each time the door is opened - it is unique event. What you need seems is to tell how many different workers logged in per day instead of unique login events, something lice LiveJournal's "social capital"

Comment: I agree that the question was not clearly explained. But I gave an example. Yes, I need to count a total number of workers logins per day, but each worker must be counted only once (during a day). (This is what you explained well in your second variant: "how many different workers logged in per day").

Comment: then edit your Q and re-word it so in future other peoples could google and find it :-D

Answer (score 5):

You want to count distinct users per day:

```
select logday, count(distinct workerid) as logincount
from logevent
group by logday
order by logday;
```

Comment: Thorsten, thank you very much for your answer. It did work! I thought about using distinct wokerid somewhere. But I did not know that I could put it directly into count().

Comment: @RomanVasin I suggest you read the Firebird language reference, for example, [`count`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-aggfuncs-count)

Answer (score 4):

You want to count the distinct workerids per day. so for that you need this query:

```
select  count(DISTINCT workerid) as logincount, logday from logevent
group by logday
order by logday
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work. The same answer ask from Thorsten.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  count(logeventid) as logincount, logday from logevent
group by logday, workerid
order by logday
```

Extra group by on workerid should eliminate the double logins.

Comment: I also thoght about adding workerid in group by. Initially (before asking the question) I added it before logday like: group by  workerid, logday. But then I tried your variant: group by logday, workerid. But both variants don't work: they produce the same results.